# Find the fixed points of the non linear system,

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following system find the fixed points
\begin{cases}
x'(t) &= x^2 - y,\\
y'(t) &= x-y.
\end{cases}

I got $y=x^2$ and $y=x$.

These are non linear systems and so we need to compute the fixed points at its Jacobian matrix.

However, I am not sure on how to do this since I don't know the stability at the fixed points. Hence, I will not be able to draw a phase portrait for it.

Comment: Can you solve the equation $x^2-x=0$?

Comment: i beleive i understand what you are trying to say. Are the fixed points(0,0) and (1,1) since i got x=0,1 after solving the equation

Comment: Right. Do you know what the Jacobi matrix is?

Comment: yes i have solved the jacobian matrix and have obtained 
at (0,0) it is stable, spiral
at(1,1) it is a saddle point

thank you for the help

Comment: This is correct. You can post the details of your calculations as an answer and accept it in some time.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian is $$\begin{pmatrix} 2x & -1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
which has trace $2x-1$ and determinant $1-2x$.

- At $(0,0)$, with trace $-1$ and determinant $1$, there is a stable spiral.
- At $(1,1)$, with trace $1$ and determinant $-1$, there is a saddle point.